# Hiding master page preview in design view?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Is there an option in VS2008, to hide master page preview in design view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the controls from the page into a user control and preview that.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: If the page has complex CSS layout, and a master pager layout, the design view  doesn't display it right, it even does not render the contents.
So the only way to preview result is to start the web-site in browser.